# based on flag checkbox disable and enable from table using angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular8

**I am having List Array like: this is getCall.**

[
{"presenter":"Bharath","topic":"Angular","status":"scheduled","emailId":"bharathkumar@gmail.com"},
{"presenter":"Sayyad","topic":"Angular","status":"organized","emailId":"raheemsayyad@gmail.com"},{"presenter":"Kanchan","topic":"APS","status":"scheduled","emailId":"kanchanubey@gmail.com"}
];

if Logged user  is  kanchanubey@gmail.com   is matches to this List of Array emailId. i need to enable checkbox . if not matches need to do disable.

Code :

private getktsession(){
console.log('==', this.sesionUser['emailid']);

```
this.service.getKtsession().subscribe(data =>{
  console.log('get', data);
  this.ktsessions = data;
  data.filter(user => {
    if(user.emailId === this.sesionUser['emailid']){
      this.isDisabled  =false;
    } else {
      this.isDisabled  =true;
      console.log('else');
      }
  });
});
```

}
HTML code is

Comment: HTml

<tr *ngFor = "let ktsession of ktsessions  >
  <td ><input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="ktsession.isSelected" [disabled]="isDisabled"></td>

.TS

private getktsession(){
    console.log('==', this.sesionUser['emailid']);
    
    this.service.getKtsession().subscribe(data =>{
      console.log('get', data);
      this.ktsessions = data;
      data.filter(user => {
        if(user.emailId === this.sesionUser['emailid']){
this.isDisabled  =false;
        } else {
          this.isDisabled  =true;
         
        }
      });
    });
  }

Comment: Are mentioned email addresses real?.. Please remove real emails from this question, if so.